# Reload a UITableView with different tableview after disclosure Indicator is pressed (Swift iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I currently have a Mapview taking up around one half of my viewcontroller and a tableView taking up the bottom half. I have a tableview of categories, and each category has its own tableview of subcategories (For example, in the food category, when you press the cell, food categories like fast food, thai food, etc show up). I was wondering how to replace the current tableview and just reload the tableview to the category array, and then revert back to the normal category tableview via gesture or button/segue.

Is this possible? It'd be great if I could get a general guideline/structure that I could use.

Comment: Do you want to have a `push segue` effect or just refresh the content of the current `tableView`?

Comment: Refresh the current tableview. So like if i clicked food, all the food categories would take place of that tableview.

Comment: You can update the content of the `array` you're using to populate the `tableView` and call `reloadData` on the `tableView`

Comment: So in my detail VC, i have a field for an array of foodtypes. So i would just set the current array I have right now (called categories) and set it equal to my other array and then reloadData() ?

Comment: I would suggest using `NSDictionary` that holds your `categories`, `food`,... and then based on whatever screen is that set the `currentArray` = `dictionary[@"key"]` (so you don't loose the data) - and then yes, call the `reloadData`

Comment: Cool that seems to work. How would you suggest navigating back? Instantantiating a navigation controller or is there a better way? Sorry I'm new to iOS

Comment: If you want to have a full functional navigation controller you can use [ContainerView](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers) (which is a better way) or you can have a condition in your code that checks if it's not the root `array` (`categories` in your case) it adds an extra row on the very top and goes back when that row is tapped